# :focus not working as expected in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a question on accessibility on a postchat survey window which I've worked on.There's a close button on the top right(as an image of X) where I've included visual focus by putting focus pseudo class, now the problem i'm facing is that the close button has white border around it when it is focused and this is happening as expected in chrome, Mozilla but in IE a blue border is coming. Can someone help me how to remove this blue border and bring white in its place?

I'm sharing the code snippet where I've used focus

```
a.close-link:focus {
    outline: 1px dotted white;
}
```

Comment: It should work fine. Which IE version are you testing against? IE < 9 has flaky support for `:focus` on `a`.

Comment: Funny title, has made me laugh! XD

Answer (score 1):

Though active and focus are to different states but you can try both at same time for your purpose i think

```css
:active       Adds a style to an element that is activated
:focus        Adds a style to an element that has keyboard input focus
:hover        Adds a style to an element when you mouse over it
:lang         Adds a style to an element with a specific lang attribute
:link         Adds a style to an unvisited link
:visited      Adds a style to a visited link
```

following source **http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp**

```js
a.close-link:focus, a.close-link:active {
        outline: 1px dotted white;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`:FOCUS` pseudo-class ***does*** work in IE, Instead, I believe your problem is with `outline` property.

Try this:

> #### IE 9
>
> George Langley wrote in to say that IE 9 apparently doesn't allow you
>   to remove the dotted outline around links unless you include this meta
>   tag:
>
> `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`

<sup><kbd>([(source)](https://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/))</kbd></sup>

Answer (score 0):

Well i've found out a workaround. For IE9 border comes by default so I've removed border now and the blue outline is no more there!

```
    a.close-link:focus {
        outline: 1px dotted white;
    }

    a.close-link img {
        border: none;
    }
```